# iOS: deauthorise device for books download

Tags: ios, books, authorization

I need to deauthorise books downloads on an iOS (16.6.1) device but the only instructions I can find are for macOS or much older iOS version (screen shots look nothing like current version) ?

I can't "deauthorise all" because I had problems earlier in the year and you can do that only once a year.